# Performing NDB Query During cronjob

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have a GAE (google app engine) app that is to parse a website at 15 minute intervals. every 15 minutes the cron will check the timestamp on the oldest data (`BitData()` in this case) to be loaded and will parse data from that point until `utc.now()`.
Unfortionetly I cannot get past the first part of querying the NDB database for the newest `BitData()` object.

Code example:

```
def bitcoincharts_last():
    q = BitData.query()
    q = q.order(BitData.tstamp)
    if q == None:
        return '0'
    else:
        return q[0]
```

This puts out an error in the log:

```
TypeError: order() expects a Property or query Order; received <class 'google.appengine.ext.ndb.model.DateTimeProperty'>
```

Using `q = q.order(-BitData.tsamp)` to reverse order the responses instead gives:

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'type'
```

I've checked my code against examples [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/mobilebasic), [here](http://dylanv.org/2012/08/22/a-hitchhikers-guide-to-upgrading-app-engine-models-to-ndb/), and the NDB Google Docs, but I cant seem to find why the query wont run.

BitData:

```
class BitData(ndb.Model):
    key = ndb.KeyProperty
    tstamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty
    price = ndb.IntegerProperty
    amount = ndb.IntegerProperty
```

Comment: What's the definition of you BitData model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model definition should be:

```
class BitData(ndb.Model):
    key = ndb.KeyProperty()
    tstamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
    price = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    amount = ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

You are just defining your Class fields to point towards the ndb Property classes, you aren't actually instantiating any of them.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I must have missed that when I switched it over from the regular DB models. Also using the minus sign before the order like so: `q = q.order(-BitData.tsamp)` still gives the same error

Comment: Are you sure? Works fine for me once you use the new Model definition I provided.

Comment: Actually your rights. I probably didn't save it in Eclipse before refreshing and then changing it again. Thank you very much!